# Смещать метку и центр карты при клике на внешнюю ссылку

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет!
Есть общая карта с несколькими метками. И есть список с описанием разных объектов и у каждого кнопка "посмотреть на карте".

разметка примерно следующая:

```
<div class="maps" id="map">
<!-- сюда вставляется карта с метками всех адресов-->
</div>

<!-- элементы внутри которых должны быть кнопки, 
перемещающие метку на карте 
или открывающие новую карту с нужной меткой -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <a href="">посмотреть на карте</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <a href="">посмотреть на карте</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <a href="">посмотреть на карте</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

карту подключаю так:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.753559, 37.609218]
            zoom: 10
        });

myMap.geoObjects
    .add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.753559, 37.609218], {
        iconCaption: "Москва",
    }))
    .add(new ymaps.Placemark([59.938531, 30.313497], {
        iconCaption: "Санкт-Петербург",
    }))
    .add(new ymaps.Placemark([56.829748, 60.617435], {
        iconCaption: "Екатеринбург",
    }));
}
```

Нужно чтобы при нажатии этой кнопки у какого-то конкретного объекта на карте оставалась только одна метка (с координатами этого объекта) или же центр смещался на центр координат выбранного адреса. Как такое реализовать?

Очень похожий пример тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_list
Но мне нужны не объекты, а только одна метка, и само меню должно добавляться в уже существующие блоки

Comment: добавьте конкретные примеры того, что уже есть, и скриншоты или более подробное описание того, что вы хотите получить. Очень мало информации

Comment: @neverd1m дополнила вопрос

Comment: есть вот такой пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/list_box_layout